# Advice on image wrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a `floating design`, but when I resize my browser, the `<p>` tag next to the `<img>` tag starts laying out into a column, instead of going under the image.
You can see the code here -> http://funkz.nfshost.com/
It's in the "**`main-bottom-post**" ID .`
I've also searched the net, but most articles are about the other way around -
making a column next to the img.
Thanks in advance,
M. K.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, how should it behave? Can you be a little more precise?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I haven't been clear - I want the text to float under the image in the main-bottom-post. Currently when i resize my browser (to look like a smaller display) the text is in a column right, to the image, but doesn't go under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/) to target a specific resolution when you want your `<p class="post-text">` to move under your image and apply a `float: left;` on it to do so.

For example :

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    p.post-text {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

This will make your `<p class="post-text">` float under the image for a screen width of between **480px** and **320px**.

You might also want to take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for further references.

Comment: Thank you, will try and post the results. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the css: `display:inline-block` when you resize your browser you get successful

Comment: I tried display:inline-block for the img, p and container tag -> nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `position` property.

or try with `media queries`

```
@media screen and (min-width: xxpx) {
   div {width: xxpx;}
 }
```

try this links

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

http://www.danstorm.com/dan-storm-article-css-15.html